# Composer install on Laravel 5.4 results Fatal Error memory size - infinite loop

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

My app kept getting Fatal error:memory crash when running `composer install`.

I'm using a vanilla install of Laravel 5.4 and also getting the same error.

```
`php artisan optimize`

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/forge/brute.ryder.io/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 549`
```

I know it's an infinite loop - changing PHP memory size results in same error- but I don't know what package composer is including that is causing it.

Starting to weed through them each until successful Composer install. 
Do you know of what else may be causing this?

Comment: I just use `laravel new myApp` and then `cd myApp` and `php artisan serve` and everything is woking fine.

Comment: It is a vanilla 5.4 install. I used that. Git was ignoring `config/` folder. But it is not listed in gitignore.     `/node_modules
/public/storage
/public/hot
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.env`

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue, but my config folder exists, still finding out what the issue is for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre... git was ignoring config on a vanilla install. Going to try to diagnose more. This fixed it.

`git add config/* -f`

Comment: `git check-ignore -v config/` showed that my `~/.gitignore_global` had config listed.